# PhoneGap for Windows Store Apps

Tags: windows-8, cordova, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Can we use PhoneGap for Windows Store Apps that will be developed using C# and Xaml? If so, can it handle all device and resolution dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking here.  If the question is "Can we use phonegap to develop an app for windows 8" the answer is yes : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_win8_index.md.html#Windows%208%20Platform%20Guide

If you're question is "can I write code for a phonegap application using C#" the answer is no.  The whole point of phonegap is that it allows you to write applications for various different platforms in HTML and Javascript.